# Change default build target from flutter for web to flutter for Android

Tags: flutter

I am using VS Code. After some experiments with building flutter for web it's began to build every project for web be default. I need to get it back by default Android version.

```
PS D:\code\2019\dart_app1\app1> flutter devices
2 connected devices:
Windows • Windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.984]
Chrome  • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 76.0.3809.132
```

```
>PS D:\code\2019\dart_app1\app1> flutter emulators
3 available emulators:
Nexus_5X_API_29  • Nexus 5X API 29  • Google • android
Nexus_9_API_28   • Nexus 9 API 28   • Google • android
flutter_emulator • flutter emulator • Google • android
To run an emulator, run 'flutter emulators --launch <emulator id>'.
To create a new emulator, run 'flutter emulators --create [--name xyz]'.
You can find more information on managing emulators at the links below:
  https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds
  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager
```

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Specify your device in `launch.json` file with `args` parameter:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": ["-d", "<device name from adb devices output>"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Or select from `vscode` bottom panel at right side. By default launcher select first available device, and `chrome device` probably always that.

Comment: complementing, I use fvm then the path is `fvm/fvm_config.json`. Ty for your help!