# How to set Android Emulator as default device in Flutter vs code?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

every time I start vscode for flutter, I have to manually switch from chrome web to android emulator. I want to set the android emulator as the default device. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: How do you like to run?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default build target from flutter for web to flutter for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886563/change-default-build-target-from-flutter-for-web-to-flutter-for-android)

Comment: Yeah, it did help. Thanks